# Where do I put the $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); to disable all jQuery Mobile loading messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

Where exactly does that line of code go for a Rails application?  Which file, and is there any additional surrounding syntax?  Does anyone have a complete example of how to disable jQuery loading messages?  I've read the documentation but I think there's just something really basic I'm missing that's not explicitly covered in the documentation.

Thanks

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.mobile
```

application.mobile.js

```
//= require jquery.mobile
```

application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery.mobile
*= require scaffolds.css
```

application.mobile.css

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery.mobile
```

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'thin'

group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'mobylette'
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'

group :test, :development do
 gem 'rspec'
 gem 'rspec-rails'
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mobile Version!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
  </script>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application.mobile.js" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application.mobile.css" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <%= yield %>

  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <%= link_to notes_path, :class => ("ui-btn-active" if action_name == 'index'), :"data-icon" => "home", :"data-iconpos" => "top" do %>
            Home
          <% end %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to new_note_path, :class => ("ui-btn-active" if action_name == 'new'), :"data-icon" => "plus", :"data-iconpos" => "top" do %>
        New Note
          <% end %>
         </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically, the moral of the story here is DONT user Gems for jQuery Mobile.  Saying they don't work would be an understatement...they get 95% of the job done but then they puke so spectacularly that it's almost comical to think you tried to use them in the first place.  These gems seem to (1) have an innate ability to explode when literally ANYTHING is updated that is remotely related to Rails and/or jQuery Mobile, (2) get abruptly and inexplicably delisted by their github owner, (3) throw awesomely rare and automagical errors, and (4) all for the awesome benefit of including MORE lines (that are by the way really sensitive to breaking) of code than if you were to just use jQuery Mobile hotlinks in the first place.

Save yourself a ton of headaches and just use hotlinks.  If not, you'll win an all-expense paid vacation to suckville, sponsored by jQuery Mobile Gems, Inc (the latest versions of which, by the way, are almost guaranteed to be out of date and completely useless).

application.html.erb

```
    <title>Hello</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: So,  just don't use the Gem.   I get that.  Did you get it working using the assets pipeline?  Can you edit your answer and put more detail about the 'recipe' that you followed to make it work.  I'd be interested in seeing your assets manifests,  and your include tags on a page that works.

Comment: So...yeah I don't think I'm using the asset pipeline for the jQuery Mobile stuff, but I didn't turn it off.  I'm just calling the jQuery mobile assets from the jquery.com site.  I edited my answer; that was the only file that needed to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be misunderstanding the `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` method a bit. I can certainly understand the confusion though. In JQM you can programatically show the loading message using `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` and then you would use `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` to hide the message. You could use that in your own ajaxing of certain content.

To disable the loading message you can use my example here.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
});
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

The mobile init binding is used to configure defaults for JQM. It must be placed in between your jQuery and JQM references to work properly. You can find more default settings [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get that run everywhere, on all your pages,  all the time,  probably the best bet would be in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb.   This assumes you are using an application wide layout.  If you had just created a new rails app using 3.X,   that's where you'd do it.

The simplest way to get it working is just stick it in the head of the layout, (ignoring the assets pipeline for now).

It sounds like (I'm not sure) that that's one bit of jquery where you DON'T want to wait for the DOM to load before you run the bit of code.  So I'd put in in a script tag right after the default javascript_include_tag that the rails app generator placed in the layout:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <script type='text/javascript>
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
  </script>
```

If that still doesn't do the trick,  you'd have to delve into the app/assets/javascripts/application.js manifest,  and enter a new line right after the one that loads jquery,  and that line would call a javascript file that contains that one line of code.

Comment: Thanks, but both of those solutions still didn't work for me.  I think I messed something up in setting up jQuery Mobile for this app, because the Loading message shows up on a basic index view and then just stays there.  Do you know of any working examples of how to implement jQuery mobile from start to finish in Rails 3.2?  All the examples I've seen are leaving out key pieces of code.

Comment: How did you include the jquery.mobile?  Are you using assets pipeline?

Comment: I updated my original post to show how I included jQuery Mobile, and yes I'm using the asset pipeline.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I see jquery.mobile in application.mobile.js manifest, by itself,  then  jquery, jquery_ujs and jquery.mobile in application.js manifest,  so which manifest are you using in your app,  what does your <%= javascript_include_tag ??? %> contain?

Comment: Updated to include application.html.erb, which has that line.

Comment: I think the second javascript_include_tag is redundant,  remove it, it's including the jquery.mobile a second time,  overriding your attempt to turn off pageLoadingMsg.

Comment: actually, you can remove the first <link> tag and the next two <script> tags,  that's being done for you by your application.js manifest and your stylesheet_include_tag

Comment: When I do that, the page literally shows up blank.  As in, anything related to jQuery Mobile doesn't work, and prevents the entire page from showing.  The generated HTML shows all the right jQuery Mobile code, but the rendered page is entirely blank (except for the title in the browser, 'Mobile Version!').

Comment: Sounds like your assets environment isn't setup correctly.  What browser are you developing with?  Do you have firebug (Firefox) or some other debugger.  You need to trace down the included javascript and make sure your javascript is actually in the files.  Look in application.rb and look for any 'config.assets*' lines,  post them.

Comment: Also look for 'assets.config*' lines in environments/development.rb and post them.

Comment: I'm using Safari.  config.assets.enabled = true, config.assets.version = '1.0' in application.rb.  When I start the Web Inspector in Safari with the <link> tag and 2 <script> tags taken out, the jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css, jquery-1.6.4.min.js, and jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js aren't in the list in the "Network" view.  When I keep the <link> tag and 2 <script> tags, those files are in that list, and the page isn't blank.

Comment: In development.rb, config.assets.compress = false and config.assets.debug = true

Comment: That gem was updated like 7 hours ago,  maybe you should update the gem and make sure you've complied with the instructions?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to run the Dummy app he has in there, and it just doesn't work.  He doesn't include what to put into the Gemfile, so I make my best guess and put in the gem 'jquery-mobile-rails.' Error message: '/Users/ajsmith8/rails_projects/launch/dummy/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::Bundler (NameError)

Comment: Second error message, after I fix application.rb:  ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'jquery'
  (in /Users/ajsmith8/rails_projects/launch/dummy/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:7)):

Comment: If there was a complete, working, current example of how to actually implement jQuery Mobile on Rails, that would pretty much do the trick.  The other example he has https://github.com/tscolari/rails-mobile-app-sample is already outdated and you have to put in hacks to make that work...which I couldn't get to work either.

Comment: You'll notice he's put a 'require' in application.rb instead of an entry in Gemfile,  not sure why he did that,  probably to keep it compatible with prior version of rails without bundler???  I don't know.  I'm due to go through this pain very shortly myself,  so I'll help in anyway I can.

Comment: Think I figured it out...posted an answer myself.  Message me or whatever if you want more info.